# Do I have to have every thing in windstad manor so my kids can move to it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I can't get kids to move into windstad manor. I got rid of my workbenches, but I did not have all the things they said are available. Can I still move my kids into it? (I do not have a spouse)

Answer (score 2):

At Mixxiphoid's suggestion, reposting Comment as an Answer.

---

Kids need beds & storage. They can sleep in either the West bedroom on the upper floor of the main hall or in the "Family bedroom" version of the west wing. You will need to have built the beds and specific chests/dressers next to them for the children to move in.